# how to send list item to dropdown in a partial view on multiple pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I am having some problem in showing data in dropdown on multiple pages.
Scenario: I have 5 pages with same partial view on all these pages.In this partial view, there are two dropdown.
Now, there are two controller one is Home controller and another is Post Controller.
Home controller's index action method is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<City> allCity = new List<city>();
    using (ApplicationDbContext dc = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
       allCity = dc.Cities.OrderBy(a => a.CityName).ToList();
    }
    ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(allCity, "Id", "CityName");
    return View();
}
```

Now, in partial view, i am sending data to dropdown like this:

```
@model App.Models.City

<div class="dropdown">
@Html.DropDownList("Id", ViewBag.CityId as SelectList, new { @class = "short_dropdown" })
```

and rendering this partial view to all the pages like this:

```
<section class="container">
   @Html.Partial("_CommentBox")
```

Now, if i see the index.cshtml page of Home Controller then values in dropdown are properly populated.
But, if i go to index page of Post controller then error is:**

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Id'.
>    System.InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Id'.

How to resolve this. Should I have to send data along with partial view. If yes, then I have two dropdown in one partial view then how to send data for these two dropdown.

Comment: Show us the code of Post controller Index method

Comment: The message means that the value of `ViewBag.CityId` is `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Post controller make the same as you did in your Home controller in order to populate `ViewBag.CityId`. And to avoid code duplication you could move it to a separate method that can be reused:

```
public static List<City> GetCities()
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext dc = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        return dc.Cities.OrderBy(a => a.CityName).ToList();
    }
}
```

and then populate `ViewBag.CityId` in **both** your controllers:

```
ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(SomeDomain.GetCities(), "Id", "CityName");
```

Comment: many many thnks for answering sir.It will work but i will have to write same code in 10 controller.Is there any way to send two viewbag  in same @html.Partial() then reuse it. Should i make a new action method which return a partial view and send multiple view bag in the return statement. I think there is a way but dont know how @Darin Dimitrov

Comment: You could write a [`custom action filter`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters) that will append this value to the view bag and then decorate your controller actions with it. This way you don't need to explicitly put this code in every controller action. Alternatively you could write a custom HTML helper that will generate those selects in your views.

Comment: Seems like it will get more complex i have never tried this okk i will try but for right now, i dont have any idea how to write

Comment: Well, read the article I have linked to: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters It would be a good start.

Comment: i need ur help sir please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412574/populate-single-dropdown-from-two-tables