# Populate single dropdown from two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, partial-views, html.dropdownlistfor

The scenario is:

Data is stored in database in project and neighbourhood tables both.
Now, i want to populate dropdown with project id and project name and neighbourhoodId and neighbourhood name.

i am right now sending through viewBag like this:

```
ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId = new SelectList(allNeighbourhood(), "Id", "NeighbourhoodName");
```

on view page, getting dropdown populated like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Locations", ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId as SelectList, "Select a location")
```

Now,how to send another viewBag in this dropdownList.

Second ques, My dropdown is in partial view So, i am sending data to partial view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_CommentBoxSection",new Neighbourhood())
```

how to send new Project()) along with neighbourhood. Is there any overload of partial where i can send both of them.
i have seen some posts relating to this title but they are something different
I have recently tried this:

```
 public class ProjectAndNeighbourhoodListItemViewModel
{
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Neighbourhood Neighbourhood { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
  //  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem()
    {
        return new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = Project.ProjectName,
            Value = Neighbourhood.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = IsSelected
        };
      }  
    }
```

and on view page directly,

```
 @model @model IEnumerable<ProjectAndNeighbourhoodListItemViewModel>
 @Html.DropDownList("Locations", Model.Select(m => m.ToSelectListItem()), "Select a location")
```

but getting System.ArgumentNullException value cannot be null i have no code in controller do i have to pass something in controller too

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to do it ?? still waiting for some help

Comment: You question is unclear. You can't post two distinct values from one select list. If you want a user to select a project and a neighborhood, then you need *two* select lists. If neighborhoods is limited based on the project selection, then you can set up a set of cascading drop downs where the first select fires an AJAX request to filter the second list.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thnks for ur comment and downvote but i think it is possible through a custom list which contains data of both tables but dont know how so i posted my question i have clearly stated in my question title Populate single dropdown from two tables not from one select List anyways thnks

Comment: The point is that you *can't*. Post values are single string-based key-value pairs. You can only post primitive types from a select.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ViewBag to pass values to your view, use ViewModels instead, it is much cleaner. The ViewModel is also a good place to create your SelectListItems. Create or map the ViewModel in your controller.

```
// ViewModel for a single selectable entry
public class ProjectAndNeighbourhoodListItemViewModel {

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public long NeighbourhoodId { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem() {
        return new SelectListItem {
            Text = ProjectName,
            Value = NeighbourhoodId.ToString(),
            Selected = IsSelected
        }
    }
}
```

In your Razor View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectAndNeighbourhoodListItemViewModel>
@* Would be even better to use a wrapper model that contains the collection of list items as property! *@

@Html.DropDownList("Locations", Model.Select(m => m.ToSelectListItem()) , "Select a location")
```

Comment: thnks for ur effort but in this viewmodel there is no Project Id. I want to populate dropdown from project tables and neighbourhood tables both

Comment: DropDownList() can only take a single collection of possible options. Create a single SelectList for your options, but populate it with SelectListItems created from both tables.

Comment: thnk u i will try asap